How to find the consecutive values in a column based on another group column
I am trying to find consecutive duplicate records based on each group and flag it as consecutive.
Below is an example i need to check the Values for one group and check if it is repeated in the next group, please provide your suggestion in r i am beginner.

i have tried with ranking in spotfire but not able to achieve the solution.

There is no example provided. Can you please check if you forgot to include it?

Apologies, added the data

A solution using dplyr package would be to group_by(Values), maybe sorting with arrange(Group), and checking if the difference between one value and the next one is equal to one with (lead(Group) - Group) == 1 . Let me know if it seems to fit your needs, I could write an answer.

can you explain the logic? Why is 36 repeated but not consecutive? It behaves the same as 45, with repeated values

@GaiaPaolini, I think that is because the pair (102, 36) is missing.  So (101,45) ; (102,45); and (103, 45) are consecutive,  but it is not the case of 36 with only (101,36); and (103, 36)

Hey, @velmurugan, please, share the data as code or, at least, as text/table. Please, don't post data as image.

A value must be in all groups to be flagged "consecutive", @velmurugan? On your example, if 45 was in groups 101 and 102, but not 103, how it should be flagged?

This worked for my test cases:
case  
when ((Max(DenseRank([Group])) over ([Values]) - Min(DenseRank([Group])) over ([Values]) + 1)=Count(DenseRank([Group])) over ([Values])) and (Count(DenseRank([Group])) over ([Values])>1) then 'Consecutive' 
when Count(DenseRank([Group])) over ([Values])=1 then Null
else 'Repeated'
end

or broken down with intermediate columns:
case  
when ([dRank]=[Count1]) and ([Count1]>1) then 'Consecutive' 
when [Count1]=1 then Null
else 'Repeated'
end

where:
[Rank2]: Max(DenseRank([Group])) over ([Values]

[Rank1]: Min(DenseRank([Group])) over ([Values]

[dRank]: [Rank2] - [Rank1] + 1

[Count1]: Count(DenseRank([Group])) over ([Values]

The idea being that there are three possible cases:
a) there is no gap between the max group and min Group for each value, and there are more than one associated Group
b) there is only one associated Group
c) everything else.
I am still assuming that Groups that appear consecutively are indeed consecutive, regardless of the group name.

Thank you so much it was really helpful to achieve it in Spotfire itself.

A possible solution based on ordered Group. Only Values that are present in all Groups are flagged. Also gaps in Group (e.g. 101,103) are considered non-consecutive through dff.
library(dplyr)

df %>% 
  arrange(Group) %>% 
  mutate(dff = c(0, diff(Group)), .by = c(Group, Values)) %>% 
  mutate(Consecutive =
    all(lag(Group) == Group - 1, na.rm=T) & n() > 1 & dff == 0, .by = Values) %>%
  select(-dff)
  Group Values Consecutive
1   101     45        TRUE
2   101     36       FALSE
3   102     45        TRUE
4   102     67       FALSE
5   103     45        TRUE
6   103     36       FALSE

Data
df <- structure(list(Group = c(101L, 101L, 102L, 102L, 103L, 103L), 
    Values = c(45, 36, 33, 67, 45, 36)), row.names = c(NA, -6L
), class = "data.frame")


This tidyverse::purrr solution marks a value as "consecutive" if its group has an immediate higher or lower. If it doesn't, marks as "repeated" if it appears elsewhere in the table.
library(tidyverse)
# ----------------

# Sample data
set.seed(100)
aux <- tibble(group = sort(rep.int(100:105, 5)), value = sample(30:50, 30, replace = TRUE))
aux <- distinct(aux, group, value)

# Consecutives
aux$flag <- map_chr(
  1:nrow(aux),
  \(x) if_else(
    any((aux$group[x] + c(-1, 1)) %in% aux$group[aux$value == aux$value[x]]), 
    "consecutive", NA_character_))

# Just repeated
aux$flag <- map_chr(
  1:nrow(aux),
  \(x) if_else(
    is.na(aux$flag[x]) & aux$value[x] %in% aux$value[-x], 
    "repeated", aux$flag[x]))

The output:
> print(aux, n = nrow(aux))
# A tibble: 27 × 3
   group value flag       
   <int> <int> <chr>      
 1   100    39 NA         
 2   100    35 consecutive
 3   100    45 repeated   
 4   100    48 repeated   
 5   100    43 NA         
 6   101    41 consecutive
 7   101    35 consecutive
 8   101    33 repeated   
 9   101    31 repeated   
10   102    36 repeated   
11   102    40 repeated   
12   102    47 consecutive
13   102    41 consecutive
14   103    32 NA         
15   103    48 consecutive
16   103    37 NA         
17   103    47 consecutive
18   103    31 repeated   
19   104    48 consecutive
20   104    33 repeated   
21   104    49 consecutive
22   104    45 consecutive
23   105    50 NA         
24   105    36 repeated   
25   105    45 consecutive
26   105    40 repeated   
27   105    49 consecutive

